# Calling sudo from a remotely executed shellscript dumps random memory?

Tags: php, bash, memory-dump

I have a PHP application that logs into the local machine via SSH, starts a shellscript and prints the output from that script back to the browser in realtime (by keeping the page loading).

However, when the shellscript hits `sudo service apache2 reload > /dev/null` 1024 bytes of seemingly random memory are dumped and output aborts while the script finishes normally.
When the connection finally terminates (for example by killing it), some additional amount of random stuff is vomited across the screen, depending on how long the connection has remained opened.

The executing PHP script just reads the SSH connection's stdout until some aborting/terminating event happens. Other than that it translates ANSI color codes to HTML `<span>`s:

```
stream_set_blocking($this->stdo, true);
fwrite($this->stdo, $cmd . "\n"); // write command to start running shellscript

$buf = '';
do
{
    $buf = fread($this->stdo, 256);

    if ($ansicolor)
        echo $this->ansicolor($buf); // color codes are translated to HTML here
    else
        echo $buf;

    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
while (strpos($buf, '$') === false);

flush();
ob_flush();
```

For all security concerned people: PHP is logging into a normal user who has "NOPASSWD" sudo for that very command only.

I can tell the `sudo` call is causing the problem because my script does frequent output of what's going on via `echo` which is displayed fine.
Also, I don't want to pipe stderr away in case of the reload failing and spitting out an actually useful error.

Installed versions of relevant things:

- PHP `5.3.3-7+squeeze17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 15:06:16)`
  I need PHP 5.3 because of legacy applications which cant handle newer versions.
- libssh2-php `0.11.0-2.1`
- OpenSSL `1.0.1e-2+deb7u7` (https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-2896)
- openssh-server `1:6.0p1-4+deb7u1`

How can I fix this problem to not dump random memory anymore?

Comment: "Dumping random memory" in the context of OpenSSL is a disturbing concept. You're using OpenSSL 1.0.1e, which has the Heartbleed bug. I strongly recommend you upgrade to 1.0.1g (or later).

Comment: @BrianKendig according to https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-2896 Heartbleed has been fixed in `1.0.1e-2+deb7u5` for wheezy. I'm also not getting any newer version through the deb-repo.

Comment: Okay, then, the first question is: is the memory dump coming from `ssh`, or from `sudo`, or from the command you're remotely executing? Try swapping things around - `sudo` to a different command, or try running that command directly from a command line... see if you can isolate the one piece of the puzzle that causes that garbage to appear.

Comment: Can you pipe it through `od -t x1 -c` and post this random output (along with the non-random output that precedes it)?

Comment: Just to make sure, you have "requiretty" disabled for this command, right?

Comment: @angrychimp Yes, requiretty is disabled.

Comment: Did you try this: sudo service apache2 reload > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: @ArunSangal as I wrote in the question: "I don't want to pipe stderr away in case of the reload failing and spitting out an actually useful error."

Comment: without it 2>&1? what if you just try & (background)

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing "memory dump" on the screen.  What you are seeing is the output of the `service` command that is on stderr.   It would usually look something like this on screen:

```
 * Reloading web server config apache2      [OK]
```

The [OK] message has some ANSI formatting going on, and this fills out the rest of the 1024 bytes.

If you want to avoid the "garbage", while still seeing errors, you want to strip out all of the ANSI formatting.  Something like this:

```
service apache2 reload >/dev/null 2> >(sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}((;[0-9]{1,3})*)?)?[m|K]//g")
```

Comment: Two things: (1) It's impossible to say for sure what the OP is seeing, since they haven't actually shown us. (2) Given the discussion of converting ANSI color codes to HTML in the question, one would *hope* that the OP can recognize ANSI escape sequences, and is talking about something else.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm making an educated guess on (1).  You could be right, in which case I'll humbly withdraw.  (2) not sure why the OP bothers to explain the HTML conversion.  It seems incidental to the question in the title.  He's only translating the final output, which won't include the "garbage" on sterr anyway.